# Removendo parte do link nas rotas ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

Meu RouteConfig está configurado desta forma:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{empresa}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { empresa = "", controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Meus acessos as controllers e actions estão ocorrendo normalmente, porem tenho chamadas à arquivos *.aspx para os meus relatórios, esses arquivos estão em um pasta chamada "**Relatorios**", quando vou realizar a chamada para eles está me retornar desta forma a url:
"http://localhost/minhaempresa/Relatorios/CustoMedio.aspx"

Desta forma ele não encontra o arquivo respectivo.

Estou necessitando acessar a url desta forma:
"http://localhost/Relatorios/CustoMedio.aspx"

Encontrei alguns exemplos como:

```
routes.Ignore("{*allaspx}", new {allaspx=@".*\.aspx(/.*)?"});

routes.IgnoreRoute("{*favicon}", new {favicon=@"(.*/)?favicon.ico(/.*)?"});

routes.IgnoreRoute("{Content}/{*pathInfo}");

routes.IgnoreRoute("myroute");
routes.IgnoreRoute("myroute/{*pathInfo}");
```

Porém não obtive sucesso com nenhum destes exemplos.

Comment: Qual versão do MVC você esta usando?

Comment: Estou utilizando a versão MVC 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acima da rota `Default`, use assim:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Relatorios",
    url: "{empresa}/Relatorios/{action}",
    defaults: new { empresa = "", controller = "Relatorios", action = "Index" }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pode criar outra rota ou modificar essa que vocês esta e deixar como abaixo :

```
     routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new {controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }

);
```